# EAL: Error disabling MSI-X interrupts for fd 29

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to dpdk helloworld application I am getting following error

[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]# ./build/examples/dpdk-helloworld -l 0-2 -n 4
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 8
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(2)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_em (8086:100e) device: 0000:00:0a.0 (socket -1)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 0
EAL: Error disabling MSI-X interrupts for fd 29
[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]# ./build/examples/dpdk-helloworld -l 0-2 -n 1
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 8
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(2)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_em (8086:100e) device: 0000:00:0a.0 (socket -1)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
hello from core 1
hello from core 2
hello from core 0
EAL: Error disabling MSI-X interrupts for fd 29
[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]#

[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]# dpdk-devbind.py --status-dev net

## Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver

0000:00:0a.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' drv=vfio-pci unused=e1000

## Network devices using kernel driver

0000:00:03.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if=enp0s3 drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci *Active*
0000:00:08.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if=enp0s8 drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci *Active*
0000:00:09.0 '82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller 100e' if=enp0s9 drv=e1000 unused=vfio-pci *Active*
[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]#

[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]# dpdk-hugepages.py -s
Node Pages Size Total
0    512   2Mb    1Gb

Hugepages mounted on /dev/hugepages
[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]#

[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]# lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
Model name:            12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12850HX
CPU family:          6
Model:               151
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
Stepping:            2
BogoMIPS:            4838.40
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht sys
call nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ss
se3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch fsg
sbase bmi1 avx2 bmi2 invpcid rdseed clflushopt md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features:
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
Caches (sum of all):
L1d:                   384 KiB (8 instances)
L1i:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
L2:                    10 MiB (8 instances)
L3:                    200 MiB (8 instances)
NUMA:
NUMA node(s):          1
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Vulnerabilities:
Gather data sampling:  Not affected
Itlb multihit:         Not affected
L1tf:                  Not affected
Mds:                   Not affected
Meltdown:              Not affected
Mmio stale data:       Not affected
Retbleed:              Not affected
Spec rstack overflow:  Not affected
Spec store bypass:     Vulnerable
Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, STIBP disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
Srbds:                 Not affected
Tsx async abort:       Not affected
[root@localhost dpdk-23.11]#

do not know how to solve the problem